missplaced /cr on trying to put matrices in an align
I'm trying to put some matrices in an align environment as follows:
\begin{align*}
    X^T\cdot J-J\cdot X&=\begin{pmatrix}
        A^T&C^T\\B^T&D^T
    \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
        0&I_2\\-I_2&0
    \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}
        0&I_2\\-I_2&0\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}

My suspect is that the latex is having trouble with the &, equation environment works just fine...

I don't have an error with your code snippet.  Could you complete it so that we see what you see?

The align environment is intended for alignment of multiple lines. Your code only has a single line, so the equation environment would be more appropriate.

\begin{align*}
    X^T\cdot J-J\cdot X &= \begin{pmatrix}
    A^T & C^T\\
    B^T & D^T
    \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & I_2\\
        -I_2 & 0
    \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & I_2\\
        -I_2 & 0
        \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
        A & B\\
        C & D
        \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Is this what you are trying to do?

Other than changing the formatting, how does this differ from OP's code?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you explain how your answer is adressing the question?

It differs from the fact that mine compiles @Teepeemm

But OP's code also compiles, despite what they say.  And neither of you have included the necessary \documentclass and \usepackage to actually get it to compile.  Is there any actual difference between your code and OP's code other than whitespace?
